# Can bitcoin purchase be tracked?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

Can a bitcoin transaction be tracked? I'm planning on buying bitcoin from coinmama.com and I'd like to ask if I can be tracked down for using my credit card? Will someone know my location or my bitcoin address if I buy it using a credit card.

Answer (score 1):

> **Can a bitcoin transaction be tracked?**

Mostly yes, all bitcoin transactions are recorded in the blockchain. There are techniques to try to cover up the trail -see Bitcoin mixers.

> **I can be tracked down for using my credit card?**

Obviously the credit-card company (& some of their employees) know you bought something from a Bitcoin exchange, likely Bitcoin. They know exactly who you are.

Obviously the Bitcoin exchange (& some of their employees) you used also know your identity and that you purchased Bitcoin with a credit card.

> **Will someone know my location or my bitcoin address if I buy it using a credit card.**

The credit card company will not know your Bitcoin address.

The Exchange (& some of their employees) know your Bitcoin-address.

They don't know your physical location unless you buy the Bitcoin in-person.

Many exchanges are required by Know Your Customer (KYC) laws to know who you are sufficiently for law-enforcement to track you down. Some of the employees of such exchanges will have access to this information.